# I am having problem with html header tag and some css,I guess

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm a very beginner at html and css. I have started learning html and a little bit of css very recently. I try html on androidz as I have no computer yet. In order to do that, I use an apk called trebedit. In my short journey, I've found a huge amount of problem .

I use header (and footer tag also) tag in html. And with css, I tried to give a colored background. But its not fit the screen. (Take a look at the picture, it has been marked) Maybe that's a silly question, but for me, its hard to solve.
Can anyone, please, tell me how I can solve this problem?

[image: This image is describing my problem]

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the margin of the page elements.
Welcome to the world of front end programming

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  background: rgb(185, 148, 148) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
 <header> </header>
```

Comment: you're welcome
I'm glad you got your answer